# How to efficiently spawn / instantiate a large amount of objects from a prefab

Tags: unity, performance, voxels

I am trying to make a game where the whole world is consists of a very large amount of cubes (sort of a Minecraft / Trove clone), but I keep running into huge performance issues due to the large amount of objects / vertices being rendered at once.

Just to clarify, the problem appears to be caused by the rendering, not the instantiation. I think so based on the fact that when I look away from the cubes, the frame rate will return back to normal (>60).

Is there any way to optimize this? Many answers to similar questions suggest disabling colliders, but that does not really seem to make much of a difference for me. I have also tried making the prefab static, but the problem still remains.

Currently I keep getting ~40 FPS with 10000 cubes (just the built-in cube shape stored as a static prefab with a disabled collider). I believe there should be a way to have a larger amount of objects on screen without having such a performance drop.

Does Unity have any way of storing information about a prefab in graphics card memory that would allow it to mass-render its instances in a more performance-efficient way (much like modern OpenGL uses vertex buffers)?

Comment: In your title you ask about **instatiating** while in the body you ask **rendering** which are two separate concerns. Could you edit your question so that it is consistent? (what of the two are you actually interested in?)

Comment: Yes, Unity supports instancing, but instancing won't save you here. Spawning gobs of prefabs is simply not the right solution to this problem. Most voxel-based games don't actually render a cube for every block in the world — they just look like they do. In reality, they render only the outermost surface — for example, a dynamically generated minimal mesh covering just the skin of the terrain. Search around here for voxel rendering and you'll find other questions about these types of optimization.

Comment: I have ran into this issue, @wondra, but the only solution I found was to have the blocks of your grid already existing, then changing texture/collider runtime. Of coursr, this may not help if you want it to have infinite terrain.

Comment: It is the spawning of new objects, by the way, not rendering

Comment: @wondra I ask about instantiating because I believe that's where the problem lies. Of course it's the rendering process that is slow, but I don't think there's a way to make it faster if I instantiate it the way I do (using a static prefab and the `Instantiate()`).

Comment: @TheMattbat999 As I said, I believe the problem is caused by each cube being rendered independently on the others instead of recycling already existing data from the previously rendered cubes. The instantiation process is right now only being done once and from what I can tell it only takes less than a second.

Comment: @DMGregory Thank you for the insight. I have realized that processing only the visible (surface) vertices / triangles would be necessary in order to make it faster, but I thought that the occlusion culling would do that for me. Is there any relatively easy approach to generating the mesh from an array of blocks? Would having a three-dimensional array (to store information about each block indexed by its world position) help?

Comment: As I mentioned, [this has been asked before](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=voxel+mesh), so I recommend reading up on that material first, and refining your question based on that background. Other strategies you can research include dispensing with meshes altogether and using a form of raymarching or octree traversal to rasterize the voxels.

Comment: @DMGregory I didn't know anything about voxels when I asked this question, thus making it impossible for me to find anything on the topic. Most of the questions I found only worked with a handful (a thousand at max) of objects, therefore I couldn't really use their answers. I have already found a kind of a solution on [this web](http://alexstv.com/), so I should be able to build the rest of what I need on top of it.

Comment: @user3043260 like I said, I have experience with creating alot of gameobjects in a short amount of time, and that will cause severe problems with performance (even after the creation). I was working with basically a Terraria clone, and it created massive lag at creation (I also did that with a 3d sandbox, too).

Comment: Rendering worked fine when they were premade into the scene

Comment: @TheMattbat999 That's clearly not the case for me. As I said, when I look away, everything works perfectly fine, so the performance issues must be caused by the rendering process. All the objects are instantiated almost immediately without any visible delay / lag.

Comment: Welcome to a stack exchange site! As a quick note, there is no such thing as necro-posting here, users are welcome to contribute at any time if it's still relevant to future visitors. If a user decides to answer in comments, there is a risk that those comments get deleted, and it's a perfectly acceptable behaviour for another user to post an answer out of those. Questions with answers are generally considered useful for future visitors; if you don't need it anymore, you're welcome to either delete the question, or leave it alone (don't accept, vote, etc.).

Comment: We're looking forward to see you contribute to the site again :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use thousands of `GameObject`s. Don't use the flyweight pattern. Do as Peter says: batch your vertices. You can learn the basics of procedural mesh construction [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GeneratingMeshGeometryProcedurally.html).

Between [batching](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DrawCallBatching.html) and [instancing](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html), you can do things with far better performance than by using thousands of `GameObject`s, which creates unnecessary overheads in such high-geometry tasks.

Golden Rule of voxel/cube terrain: NEVER use one object instance per tile, except possibly in exceptional circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like what you are looking for is Occlusion Culling.

Essentially if you are running a Minecraft like game, the renderer is going to try to render everything that is currently being seen by the camera even GameObjects that are obscured by other GameObjects. The problem occurs, because you what you actually want is to only render things that are actually showing, that is, only the GameObjects that are in view and not being blocked by other GameObjects.

Occlusion Culling to the rescue! Occlusion Culling fixes your problem by saying "Hey I know there is a ton of GameObjects in front of me, but can you only render the ones that the player is actually seeing, that is, not the ones that are being blocked by other GameObjects?"

Hopefully this makes sense!

Check this [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html) for a nice guide from Unity that explains exactly what I'm talking about...much better then I did.

Comment: I am aware of culling, I have mentioned it in the comments, but it really doesn't solve the problem. Even with just a flat plane of 100x100 cubes (all cubes are in sight) the culling seems to have no effect. It appears that I will really have to convert the surface of all the blocks into a single mesh in order to speed up the rendering. I just wasn't familiar with the concept of voxels when asking the question. As I said, culling is not going to help, because I want to be able to have a 500x500 cubes flat plane and culling is not going to help me with that.

Comment: @user3043260 The solution is to render a flat plane instead of 25'000 cubes representing a flat plane. There are several ways of doing this, voxel is one keyword, and another band-aid is self-made batching.

Comment: @Peter The surface of the world is obviously not supposed to be completely flat which makes it quites difficult to use basic shapes. Besides I've mentioned earlier that I have been doing the static batching and it didn't help, so I doubt doing it myself would yield any better result.

Comment: @user3043260 Just humor me. Make these 10'000 cubes you mentioned into 3 models of 3'500 cubes each, using a single gameobject for each, and your framerate will be fine (unless your fragment shader is the problem)

Comment: The reason occlusion culling doesn't help much in this case is that Unity's occlusion culling uses pre-computed data. If you're spawning your blocks at runtime, Unity has no idea what occludes what, so it's not able to save rendering time in this case.

Comment: @DMGregory, oh, well I guess it makes sense, but I haven't really considered that..

Comment: @Peter You do realize that these cubes must be independent of each other, right? I kinda said that in the comment you replied to, so I assume you are aware of that. Of course if I use a single large block instead of a large amount of small blocks, there will be a significantly lower amount of vertices to work with, thus making the rendering much easier. But that's really beside the point I was going for.

Comment: Peter is describing batching, where you  put all the vertices and faces for a group of blocks into a single mesh. The total amount of vertices & triangles remains the same, but it can be submitted to the GPU in fewer draw calls, which can be a substantial savings. You don't necessarily lose independence of the blocks in this situation, you just re-generate the group mesh when some of its blocks need to change. Unity does a degree of this for you automatically though, so if it's still slow you might need to dig into more aggressive optimisations as discussed above.

Comment: One thing that could be useful to you is the Flyweight pattern. Seems like this might be what you are looking for. Check here http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/flyweight.html. 

Essentially it's a way of grabbing all the similar data and having only one reference to that rather than instantiating the same data over and over and over again.